# C++ auto vs auto&

Tags: c++, casting, reference, auto

if I have a function:

```
Foo& Bar()
{
   return /// do something to create a non-temp Foo here and return a reference to it
}
```

why is this:

```
auto x = Bar(); /// probably calls copy ctor - haven't checked
```

not the same as this?

```
auto &x = Bar(); /// actually get a reference here
```

*(Actually, I'd expect the second version to get a reference to a reference, which makes little sense.)*

If I explicitly specified the type of `x` as a value or a reference, I'll get what I expect (of course). I would expect, though, that `auto` would compile to the return type of `Bar()`, which, in this case, is a reference.

Is there an implicit cast between `Foo` and `Foo&` that comes into play here?

(Spec references accepted, though I'm getting tired of reading committee-speak.)

(Second use of time machine will be making C++ pass by reference by default. With a `#pragma compatibility` trigger for compiling C code. ARGH.)

Comment: Such a waste of the time machine.  Pass-by-reference is evil.  Aliases of mutable data create data races, ruin optimization opportunities, etc.  Making it default would be terrible.

Comment: @BenVoigt good points, but I spend a lot of time typing 'const T&' that I'd rather spend drinking. :/

Comment: You might be using the wrong language.  I'm sure that others fit your preferred programming style better.

Comment: `probably calls copy ctor - haven't checked` Why don't you check it, then, before you make random assertions about its behaviour? Your entire question is predicated on this assertion.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm using multiple languages. I asked because I wanted to know *why* this didn't do what I expect. (That is, why is my expectation incorrect, and how can I adjust my perspective to better align with that of the language designers.) "You might be using the wrong language" doesn't really answer what, why or how.

Comment: I meant about default pass by reference saving you a few keystrokes. The question itself is quite acceptable.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah - got it. I misread. Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The type deduction for `auto` works exactly the same as for templates:

- when you deduce `auto` you will get a value type.
- when you deduce `auto&` you wil get a non-const reference type
- when you deduce `const auto&` you will get a const reference
- when you deduce `auto&&` you will get

  - a non-const reference if you assign a non-const reference
  - a const reference if you assign a const reference
  - a value when you assign a temporary

Comment: welcome to Stack! Great answer. I hope you hang out and continue to contribute both Q and A.

Comment: Although it isn't terribly explicit, this does explain why.  **For consistency with templates.**  Consistency is good because (1) programmers are already familiar with the rules and (2) Compilers can reuse the existing template type deduction logic for `auto`.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case it is also bad because the template rules are about as clear as mud...

Comment: What's the difference between a value type and a non-const reference type? i.e. `auto` vs `auto &`. I understand it would be different as function signatures, but I don't understand when it's in variable declarations.

Answer (score 15):

Taken directly from Herb Sutter's [blog post](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/07/gotw-92-solution-auto-variables-part-1/):

> auto means “take exactly the type on the right-hand side, but strip off top-level const/volatile and &/&&.”

Comment: Well, that was fast. I guess that's why they didn't call it `var`. :/

Comment: This explains *what*, but not *why*.