# C++ Swapping pointers - can't reproduce auto type by defining type explicity

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Doing exercise 6.22 in C++ Primer, **a function swapping two pointers**:

```cpp
void swap(int*& a, int*& b) {
    auto temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 15;
    int b = 4;
    int* p1 = &a;
    int* p2 = &b;
    cout << "p1 address: " << p1 << "; p1 value: " << *p1 << "\np2 address: " << p2 << "; p2 value: " << *p2 << endl;
    swap(p1, p2);
    cout << "p1 address: " << p1 << "; p1 value: " << *p1 << "\np2 address: " << p2 << "; p2 value: " << *p2 << endl;
}
```

Not sure if it's correct, but it works as expected, the values and addresses are swapped. I hover in MS Visual Studio over the `a` inside `swap` function:

[image]

It tells me the type is `int*&`, but changing the definition of `temp` to `int*& temp = a` breaks the program:

```
p1 address: 004FFE00; p1 value: 15
p2 address: 004FFDF4; p2 value: 4
p1 address: 004FFDF4; p1 value: 4
p2 address: 004FFDF4; p2 value: 4
```

What is the correct type here? What's the logic behind MS Visual Studio type tooltip?

Comment: The tooltip is informing you on the type of `a` not `temp`. Here `auto temp` is `int* temp` not `int* & temp`. Whether or not `temp` uses type deduction has no impact on the type of `a`.

Comment: `temp = a` needs to _copy_ the pointer, not create a new alias (reference) to it.

Comment: [ProTip] `auto`, and template parameters, will never deduce to a reference type.  If you want a reference type, you must specify it by adding the `&` after the type.

Comment: This is perhaps a duplicate of [C++ auto vs auto&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832862/c-auto-vs-auto).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux silly me! But of course it does! It was rough making myself go back to learning C++ after 2 weeks, so I got terribly rusty. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `temp` is of type `int*`, not `int*&`. If you want it to be a reference to a pointer, you can declare the type explicitly or use `auto&`. However, what you really want is `int*` anyway. Think about how you would write this if you were swapping two `int`s instead:

```
void swap(int& a, int& b) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Here, you want `temp` just to be an `int` because you just want it to store the value of `a` so you can copy it to `b`. There is no need for it to be a reference.

As to your other question, what is happening when `temp` is a reference?

- `a` = 15
- `b` = 4
- Call `swap()`
- `temp` references `a`
- `a` references `b` (so `temp` references `b`)
- `b` references `temp` (so `b` references `b`)
- Both `a` and `b` now reference the value 4

To see this in action, walk through the function in debug mode and examine the pointer addresses and values at each step.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, really cleared up my confusion on this. And debug suggestion is absolutely correct, I should have thought of it.

Answer (score 2):

`swap` function can be changed like this.

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    auto temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

First your question is what type of `int*&`. in my function, your question is same what type of `T&`. `T&` mean is reference `T`. so `int*&` mean is reference `int*`.

this is why `P2` is not changed when use `int*&`.
but if you use `auto`, `temp` type is `int*`. this is why it works so well.

Comment: If you want to genericize the function, that's fine. You should also be moving everything.

Comment: @sweenish
your comment is good opinion. but I wanted to focus on type problem.
Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: If you're going beyond the OP's question, I say go all the way or at least state that it's still incomplete.

Comment: I haven't yet learned templates, but my guess on the meaning of this is probably correct. What @sweenish means is that you should use `T temp = a;` instead of `auto temp = a;`?